# Angular 4: how can I display a template when I have a template reference?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have template:

```
<ng-template #templateVar> my content </ng-template>
```

Now I can to do this:

```
<div *ngIf="false; else templateVar"></div>
```

and this template will be rendering. Obviously this is not the right way. How to do it right?

Comment: is false in ngIf is for simplifing purpose your you have it in your code for real?

Comment: wont it be similar to what ngIf  will be without the newest change that angular 4 came up with i:e the else block .

Answer (score 1):

All simple:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templateVar"></ng-container>
```